# A Question About the Inflection Points of a Function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is the following statement true?

Every inflection point of a function $f$ occurs at some critical point of the function's derivative $f^\prime$.

Clearly, not all critical points of $f^\prime$ is an inflection point of $f$. Classic example being,
$$
f(x) = x^4
$$
Since $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$, it is a critical point of $f^\prime$, however, it is not an inflection point of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I will quote myself from Wikipedia.

For a function $f$, if its second derivative $f''(x)$ exists at $x_0$ and $x_0$ is an inflection point for $f$, then $f''(x_0) = 0$, but this condition is not sufficient for having a point of inflection, even if derivatives of any order exist.

In this case, one also needs the lowest-order (above the second) non-zero derivative to be of odd order (third, fifth, etc.).
If the lowest-order non-zero derivative is of even order, the point is not a point of inflection, but an undulation point.

However, in algebraic geometry, both inflection points and undulation points are usually called inflection points.
An example of an undulation point is $x = 0$ for the function $f$ given indeed by $f(x) = x^4$.

In the preceding assertions, it is assumed that $f$ has some higher-order non-zero derivative at $x$, which is not necessarily the case.
If it is the case, the condition that the first nonzero derivative has an odd order implies that the sign of $f'(x)$ is the same on either side of $x$ in a neighbourhood of $x$.
If this sign is positive, the point is a rising point of inflection; if it is negative, the point is a falling point of inflection.

**Inflection points sufficient conditions.**

$1)$
A sufficient existence condition for a point of inflection in the case that $f(x)$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable in a certain neighbourhood of a point $x_0$ with $k$ odd and $k \geq 3$, is that $f^{n}(x_0) = 0$ for $n = 2, \ldots, k-1$ and $f^{k}(x_0) \neq 0$.
Then $f(x)$ has a point of inflection at $x_0$.

$2)$
Another more general sufficient existence condition requires $f''(x_0 + \epsilon)$ and $f''(x_0 − \epsilon)$ to have opposite signs in the neighbourhood of $x_0$. $\textit{(Bronshtein and Semendyayev 2004, p. 231)}.$

Answer (score 0):

At the point of inflection $x=a$ of $f(x)$, $f''(a)=0$ and $f''(a-h)f''(a+h)<0$. While passinf through $x=a$ the function changes it convexity.
$F(x)=\pm x^{2n+1}, n=1,2,3,...$ has $x=0$ as the point of inflection. Similarly,
$f(x)=\pm \sin x.\pm \tan x$ also have point of inflection at $x=0$.